# counting a range (rows) begingin in B3

Tags: excel, vba

I have data that starts in B3 and is dynamic so its range may be 5 rows to 500.  I want to loop through the number of rows in the range.

This is for a data query on number of report checked in.

```
Dim range1 As Range

Set range1 = Sheet1.Range("B3 : B" & Cells(Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Rows
```

The result should be a range B3:B46 or whatever the end row number is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("B3:B" & Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        'Do your stuff
    Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim range1 As Range
Dim x as long

With Sheet1
    x= .Cells(.rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set range1 = .Range("B3", .Cells(x,2))
End with
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it that will give you the last row that has data in it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RowCount()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    With WS
        lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use the `.End(xlUp)` property.

```
Dim rng as Range: Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B3:B" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Now you have `B3:B<last_row>` stored in the variable `rng`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am having a 1004 Auto fill error: Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Below is my code:

```
Range("A1:V50000").Select
Range("D6").Activate
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("A:A").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "key"
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("G1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("H1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("G1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Name"
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Customer ID"
Range("G2").Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFNA(IFNA(INDEX(NS!R2C1:R1048576C9,MATCH(ACHW!RC[6],NS!R2C5:R1048576C5,0),1),INDEX(Uniques!R2C1:R1048576C4,MATCH(ACHW!RC[6],Uniques!R2C2:R1048576C2,0),1)),"""")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ACHW").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ACHW").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ACHW").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A:Y")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Columns("A:Y").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 31.43
Sheets("Import").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
```

End Sub